# How does this algorithm fare against counting sort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, analysis

I was going through some code challenges and came across this one: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/countingsort4/problem

It basically has to do a counting sort but with a simple caveat. Being completely unaware of counting sort, I wrote the following algorithm, it passes all the test cases but I would like someone to help me in understanding my algorithm and counting sort algorithm and how mine is worse:

```
function countSort(arr) {
    const toBeReplaced=(arr.length/2);
    let mapOfString={};
    let distinctIntegers=[];
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        let insertDash=false;
        if(i<toBeReplaced) {
            insertDash=true
        }
        let x=arr[i][0];
        let s=arr[i][1];

        if(!mapOfString[x]){
            mapOfString[x]=[];
            insertDash?mapOfString[x].push('-'):mapOfString[x].push(s);
            distinctIntegers.push(x)
        } else{
           insertDash?mapOfString[x].push('-'):mapOfString[x].push(s);
        }  
    }
    const sortedDistinctIntegers=distinctIntegers.sort((a,b)=>{
        if(parseInt(a)>parseInt(b)){return 1}
        else if(parseInt(a)<parseInt(b)){return -1}
        else {return 0}
    });
    let finalString='';
    sortedDistinctIntegers.forEach(elem=>{
        const charLen=mapOfString[elem].length;
        for(let i=0;i<charLen;i++){
            finalString=finalString+mapOfString[elem][i]+' ';
        }
    })
    console.log((finalString.substring(0,finalString.length-1)))
}
```

Comment: You are using the native `sort` method... so then you are not *really* implementing your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: Also, information that is necessary to understand the question should not be behind a link.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/